# Class and member function template specialization gone wrong

Tags: c++, class, templates, visual-studio-2013, template-specialization

I am trying to specialize a `Color` class and it's member function `to()` in order to convert from one colorspace to another and back. Here's what I have so far:

```
enum ColorSpace {
    BGR, RGB, LAB, HSV, XYZ, YUV, HSL, CMY, YIQ, LUV, HLAB, LCH, OHTA
};

template<ColorSpace _CS, typename _Dtp> class Color;

template<typename _Dtp>
class Color<RGB, _Dtp> {

public:

    Color(_Dtp R, _Dtp G, _Dtp B) : R(R), G(G), B(B) { ;; };
    Color() : Color(0, 0, 0) { ;; };
    ~Color() { ;; };

    _Dtp R, G, B;

    template<ColorSpace _CS, typename _Dtp2 = _Dtp>
    Color<_CS, _Dtp2> to<>();

    template<typename _Dtp2 = _Dtp>
    Color<HSV, _Dtp2> to<HSV, _Dtp2>() {
        Color<HSV, _Dtp2> res;

        rgb2hsv(R, G, B, res.H, res.S, res.V);

        return res;
    }

};

template<typename _Dtp = double>
class Color<HSV, _Dtp> {

public:

    Color(_Dtp H, _Dtp S, _Dtp V) : H(H), S(S), V(V) { ;; };
    Color() : Color(0, 0, 0) { ;; };
    ~Color() { ;; };

    _Dtp H, S, V;

    template<ColorSpace _CS, typename _Dtp2 = _Dtp>
    Color<_CS, _Dtp2> to<>();

    template<typename _Dtp2 = _Dtp>
    Color<RGB, _Dtp2> to<RGB, _Dtp2>() {
        Color<RGB, _Dtp2> res;

        hsv2rgb(H, S, V, res.R, res.G, res.B);

        return res;
    }

};
```

Each colorspace has each one class. Each class has specialized functions `to()` for every possible conversion. However, I am only posting 2 of them for obvious reasons. So, when I try to use the conversion function:

```
Color<RGB, double> c(255, 255, 125);

Color<HSV, double> c2 = c.to<HSV, double>();
```

I get the following error:

> Error: class "Color" has no member "to"

My last problem comes when I try to use a default type for class `Color`:

```
template<typename _Dtp = double>
class Color<RGB, _Dtp> {
...
...
```

In that case I can't even write this:

```
Color<RGB> c;
```

It gives me this error:

> Error: expected a declaration

Comment: [OT]: `_CS` and `_Dtp` are reserved name (_ followed by capital letter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be simpler to add constructor for conversion:

```
enum ColorSpace {
    BGR, RGB, LAB, HSV, XYZ, YUV, HSL, CMY, YIQ, LUV, HLAB, LCH, OHTA
};

template <ColorSpace, typename = double> class Color;

template <typename T>
class Color<RGB, T> {
public:

    Color(T R, T G, T B) : R(R), G(G), B(B) {}
    Color() : Color(0, 0, 0) {}
    Color(const Color&rhs) = default;
    ~Color() = default;

    T R, G, B;

    template <typename T2>
    /*explicit*/ Color(const Color<HSV, T2>& rhs) 
    {
        hsv2rgb(rhs.H, rhs.S, rhs.V, R, G, B);
    }
};
template <typename T>
class Color<HSV, T> {
public:
    Color(T H, T S, T V) : H(H), S(S), V(V) {}
    Color() : Color(0, 0, 0) {}
    Color(const Color&rhs) = default;
    ~Color() = default;

    T H, S, V;

    template <typename T2>
    /*explicit*/ Color(const Color<RGB, T2>& rhs) 
    {
        rgb2hsv(rhs.R, rhs.G, rhs.B, H, S, V);
    }

};
```

With possible usage:

```
Color<RGB, double> c(255, 255, 125);

Color<HSV, double> c2{c};
```

Answer (score 1):

You code should looks like this:

```
enum ColorSpace {
    BGR, RGB, LAB, HSV, XYZ, YUV, HSL, CMY, YIQ, LUV, HLAB, LCH, OHTA
};

template<ColorSpace _CS, typename _Dtp> class Color;

template<typename _Dtp>
class Color<RGB, _Dtp> {

public:

    Color( _Dtp R, _Dtp G, _Dtp B ) : R( R ), G( G ), B( B ) { ;; };
    Color() : Color( 0, 0, 0 ) { ;; };
    ~Color() { ;; };

    _Dtp R, G, B;


    template<ColorSpace _CSO, typename _Dtp2> struct STo;
    template<typename _Dtp2> struct STo<HSV, _Dtp2>
    {
        Color<HSV, _Dtp2> to()
        {
            Color<HSV, _Dtp2> res;

            rgb2hsv( R, G, B, res.H, res.S, res.V );

            return res;
        }
    };

    template<ColorSpace _CSO, typename _Dtp2>
    Color<_CSO, _Dtp2> to()
    {
        STo<_CSO, _Dtp2> object;
        return object.to();
    }

};

template<typename _Dtp>
class Color<HSV, _Dtp> {

public:

    Color( _DtpH, _DtpS, _DtpV ) : H( H ), S( S ), V( V ) { ;; };
    Color() : Color( 0, 0, 0 ) { ;; };
    ~Color() { ;; };

    _DtpH, S, V;

    template<ColorSpace _CSO, typename _Dtp2> struct STo;
    template<typename _Dtp2> struct STo<RGB, _Dtp2>
    {
        Color<RGB, _Dtp2> to()
        {
            Color<RGB, _Dtp2> res;

            hsv2rgb( H, S, V, res.R, res.G, res.B );

            return res;
        }
    };

    template<ColorSpace _CSO, typename _Dtp2>
    Color<_CSO, _Dtp2> to()
    {
        STo<_CSO, _Dtp2> object;
        return object.to();
    }
};
```

You can't just write function specialization without definition. That is why you should remove brackets <> from the "to" function. But in this case we got another problem - we can't use partial specialization fro function, but for classes can. in this case I use "to" function like entry for possible struct specialization "STo"

Comment: You mean this: `template<ColorSpace _CS, typename _Dtp2 = _Dtp> Color<_CS, _Dtp2> to<>();` Even if I remove it I get the same error.

Comment: Ohh I see you literally meant only `<>`. Okay, in that case I get a new error: `illegal use of explicit template arguments`

Comment: Yes. The problem, that function cannot be partially specialized

Comment: I found solution. Will give you answer in this post

Comment: So, instead of partially  specialize the function, I actually specialize a struct which then use inside the function. Nice approach, thanks.

Comment: This won't work because `STO` can't access `R`, `G`, `B` since they 're not static.